# Can the Ender 3 Pro be upgraded to use PETG

Tags: creality-ender-3, nozzle, petg

Is it possible to buy/upgrade the nozzle on my Ender 3 Pro to one that is suited for handling the higher temperatures needed to effectively print with PETG filament?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hotend upgrade is required to print PETG on an Ender 3 (pro or any other variant). The stock hotend can be used at temperatures up to 250 ˚C, and 230-245 ˚C is the range typically recommended for PETG. I print it at 245 ˚C.

You may however want to upgrade the extruder. The stock extruder lacks both torque and grip, and significantly skips/slips when trying to print PETG at any significant speed. Going over 40 mm/s or so is likely to produced failed prints. Look for an extruder with gear reduction and a hob that's designed to grip the filament better (vs the flat one that comes with the printer) or even dual driven hobs.

Comment: would it be one made by the same company, im somewhat new to this so I'm not too sure where I would look etc

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of simple drop-in-replacement geared extruder is best for Ender 3 type machines these days. I have a rather fancy remote direct drive extruder on mine, which I'm very happy with, but you don't have to go that direction to get good results. I know a lot of ppl use Bondtech BMG or clones of it and recommend them, but there might be something designed for more direct mounting on E3 that's easier and less expensive.

Comment: would it be easier just to reduce the speed, or would that cause worse problems? I think I found one that is compatible but I'd like a second opinion lol Redrex Upgraded Aluminum Bowden Extruder with 40 Teeth MK8 Drive Gear for Ender 3 V2,Ender 3 Pro,Ender 3,CR 10 and Other Reprap Prusa 3D Printers https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07DDGGN92/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_glt_i_KM48SA9GKYMGPXNEP7GD

Comment: I also found replacement grip gears for lack of a better term, that have solid reviews so that is probably a better idea.

Comment: @TristanAdams be sure to check that you can remove your hob before spending on a replacement.  My Ender 3 has a pressed-on hob, non-removable (without a wheel puller).  Cheaper for Creality, requires a new stepper if I want to replace the hob.

Comment: good point I'll check after my current print is finished. :)

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon yeah I'd need a new stepper thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Still not expensive -- seems to me they run around $20 for the stepper only.